Could not determine the dependencies of task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle ' in Flutter Project
After upgrading my Android Studio to the latest version (Ladybug), I encountered the following error:

To resolve this, I updated my Gradle version and Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version. However, after making these updates, I am now facing a new issue:
Steps to Reproduce
Upgrade Android Studio to the latest version (Ladybug).
Update Gradle and AGP versions to be compatible with Java 21.
Attempt to build the project

i am used this one in setting and wrapper
plugins {
//id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0"
id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}





Wrapper
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip

Kotlin version 1.9.22
Flutter version flutter_windows_3.24.3-stable
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.2'


So what is your question?
